# Manully add csrf token With Slim ,Axios and ForData

Tags: vue.js, csrf, slim, axios

I have a a modal that would submit a file without using an actual form, I am using FormData, so upload it to server. This will work if csrf token is disabled, my question is, how would I send the csrf token manually? I am using slim,axios and vuejs.

```
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('fileme',file);
  axios.post(uyab.uploadUrl, formData,{
     headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'csrf_name': uyab.csrf_name,
        'csrf_value': uyab.csrf_value,

         'Accept': 'application/json',
     },
   })
```

But this will return error of failed csrf token

I created a function that would fetch csrf name and values from specific routes, and thus returning with correct values, the only problem is I dont know how to make it work in vuejs using spa approach